# Mysql find date that is bigger than today but if 0000-00-00 format

Tags: php, mysql, date

how can I find something that has date bigger than today, but the date format in the database is 0000-00-00.. Sample query is:

```
$query='select voucherpercent from customers 
where voucher="'.mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['voucher']).'" and 
vouchervalid > now() and voucher_used="0"';
```

Thank you

Comment: *"but the date format in the database is 0000-00-00"* - There's a reason.

Comment: you are messed up with those commas ..:o

Comment: what commas? what you mean?

Comment: @Europeuser,First Please check manually with this query => SELECT voucherpercent FROM customers
WHERE vouchervalid > NOW() & check result of above query ! It's perfect working at my end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with `date()` to get today date

```
$query='select voucherpercent from customers 
where voucher="'.mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['voucher']).'" and 
vouchervalid > "'.date('Y-m-d').'" and voucher_used="0"';
```